# Cartesian product of Cantor set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness, cantor-set

Let $C$ be the Cantor set and $S:=C\times C$. Let $f(x,y):S\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x,y)=\lVert (x,y)\rVert$, so $f$ is continuous.. Here I am negating the generalized Extreme value theorem: Let $V$ be a normed vector space, $f:V\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function; if $S$ is *not* compact, $f$ will *not* attain its sup *or* inf values on $S$.
Suppose $S$ is not compact. But $f(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \sqrt{2}$ and $f(x,y) =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge 0$ (since $C\subset [0,1]$). Thus $f$ attains *both* inf and sup on $S$, a contradiction. Hence, $C\times C$ is compact.

Please let me know if my proof looks fine.

Comment: A continuous function may attain its infimum and supremum whether the domain is compact or not. Extremely simple example: constant functions.

Comment: The extreme value theorem says "if a set is compact then all continuous real valued functions on that set attain their sup and inf". A kind of converse (not negation) would say "if a set is not compact then all continuous real valued functions on that set do not attain their sup and inf". This converse is very much false, as Daniel Fischer has demonstrated using the example of constant functions.

Comment: What about the negation of this theorem, what does it sound like?

Comment: The negation would be "there exists a compact set $S$ and a continuous real valued function $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ does not attain its sup or $f$ does not attain its inf". Because of the logical form of this statement (in particular, the fact that it *existentially* quantifies $S$), there is no way to say "suppose $S$ is not compact; ...; then we have contradicted the extreme value theorem, so actually $S$ had to be compact".

Comment: What would be a better way to prove the compactness of $C\times C$? I have no idea, would appreciate a hint.

Comment: Tychonoff does it once you know $C$ is compact; or you can use Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: Let $(x_n, y_n)$ be a sequence in $C\times C$. Since $C$ is bounded, by Bolzano-Weierstrass, $x_n$ has a subsequence $x_{f(n)}$ converging to $x \in C$, and $y_n$ has a subsequence converging to $y \in C$ (since $C$ is closed). Hence, $C\times C$ is compact by definition.

Comment: @sequence Technically you need to extract your second subsequence from $x_{f(n)}$, so that the $x$ coordinates still converge. But yes, that works, and indeed this shows that any finite product of sequentially compact sets is sequentially compact in the product topology. You can use diagonalization to extend this to countable products.

Comment: @Ian, can you please clarify what exactly stands behind the introduction of a second subsequence? Is it the rates of convergence of $x_n$ and $y_n$, which need to coincide? Which is probably not what it is.

Comment: @sequence If you just extract $f(n)$ so that $x_{f(n)}$ converges then $y_{f(n)}$ needn't converge. Similar for the other way. You need a single subequence $f(n)$ so that $x_{f(n)}$ and $y_{f(n)}$ both converge. The most straightforward way to do that given what you know about $\mathbb{R}$ is to extract $f(n)$ so that $x_{f(n)}$ converges and then extract a further subsequence $g(f(n))$ from $f(n)$ so that $y_{g(f(n))}$ also converges.

Comment: @Ian, actually in my proof on paper I wrote $x_{f(n)}$ and $y_{g(n)}$, where the $g(n)$ ensures that $y_{g(n)}$ converges. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Again, you can't just take $g(n)$ separately; you need to extract the $y$-converging subsequence from the $x$-converging subsequence.

Comment: Why is that so? If $g(n)$ ensures that $y_{g(n)}$ converges to $y$, and $x_{f(n)}$ converges to $x$, then shouldn't $(x_n, y_n)$ necessarily converge to $(x,y)$? Can you please show a counterexample?

Comment: Let's say that $x_{2n}$ converges to $x$ and $y_{3n}$ converges to $y$; then $x_{3n}$ and $y_{2n}$ each needn't converge. But $x_{6n}$ and $y_{6n}$ will both have to converge.

Comment: Right, but if $f(n) = 2n$ and $g(n) = 3n$, then shouldn't $(x_{f(n)}, y_{g(n)})$ converge to $(x,y)$?

Comment: That's not one sequence of vectors, though.

Comment: It looks like we have two separate sequences embedded into one: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(x_{f(n)}, y_{g(n)})=(x,y)$.

Comment: OK now I know what you mean. Thank you.